# how to connect local meteor project db with mongolab cloud database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mlab

I'm new to meteor and also mongoDB, I successfully export mongoDB from my local meteor project. And successfully import it into the mongo lab.

But I unable to connect with cloud mongo lab database with my local meteor project. I followed mongo lab instructions. But i failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before meteor command in console:

```
 $export MONGO_URL=mongodb://<usr>:<pwd>@<host>.mongolab.com:35448/<DB_name>
```

Then:

```
 meteor
```

You have to check user, password, host, port and DB name

Comment: I'm using windows OS. Because of that I'm unable to use export command. So I used "SET" instead of "export" command. But it doesn't work. 
That command ran without getting any message. Only print empty line in cmd.

Comment: Check first: `echo %MONGO_URL%`. You can set MONGO_URL in global settings, but then you have to restart cmd shell

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows command prompt? first check by typing below command

**meteor mongo --url**

above command will display your mongo url.If you want to run any other database in your local app, go to root folder and type below command

**set MONGO_URL=mongodb://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[databasename]**

eg-**set MONGO_URL=mongodb://root:abcde@ds049476.mlab.com:48474/mydb**

above command is working on windows